# Access a variable from a controller using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a variable tokens which is used as an OTP.It is also stored in the Session variable. I want that tokens to be accessible in JavaScript. So I created a function to return the variable.

```
    function submitotp() {
        var re = new RegExp("^[A-Z]{6}$");
        var term = document.getElementById("otpinp").value;
        var count = 0;
        if (re.test(term)) {

            $("#sup2").hide();
            $("#sup3").show();

            return true;

        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
```

and my returning function is

```
public string tokens(string token)
    {
        token = Session["otp"].ToString();
        return token;
    }
```

I want to access tokens and check if it matches that of a textbox.
Edit: It is an MVC code.

Comment: So, what's your actual question?

Comment: I can't access the tokens function in that script and can't find a way to access the tokens.

Comment: The easiest way is probably to write the value to a js variable in your view: `var top = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tokens))`. JsonConvert is found in the NewtonSoft.Json package. Otherwise you'll need to make Ajax calls, if you need the value at runtime.

Comment: I need the value at runtime as Session["otp"] is assigned at runtime. I am new to ajax. What is ajax call I should make.

Comment: No need to make an ajax call, just add your token variable into ViewData and simply use it on view...

Comment: You might have a look at SignalR to get an experience you are looking for.

Comment: I just need to check the otp generated in the controller and the input entered in the textbox. Is there any other way?

Comment: <div id="tst"> 
            <input id="otptxt" value="@ViewData["otp"]" />
        </div> I used this field so that I can access this in js but after the i set this div to update in the Ajaxform using AjaxOptions UpdateTargetId = "tst". The js doesn't execute. @ChristophHerold.

Comment: If you need some js to execute after the update, you can either use the OnSuccess parameter to specify a function to execute with the result of the call, or add a script block to the partial view returned by the action to which you are submitting. Since you are using the UpdateTargetId, I would suggest using the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Put your Session["otp"] into ViewData["otp"] and use it on your view like below

In Controller

```
ViewData["otp"] = Session["otp"];
```

In View

```
@ViewData["otp"]
```

Comment: var temp = '@ViewData["otp"]'. Is this the way to access ViewData in JS? When I use this. temp is set as a text for an alert and the alert comes up empty.

Comment: Yes, it is. Then, you can use `temp` in js.

Comment: But, be aware, the value is only updated, when you reload the view. So, don't expect any changes on the server side to be immediately visible on a previously loaded page.

Comment: It will only work if your script is on same view but if your script is in external file, you have to set temp in your view and then use temp in your script like below
On View
var temp = '@ViewData["otp"]'
In JS
alert(temp);

Comment: my whole page is in a view(single view multiple divs). If you succeed at one step and other one opens.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post("@Url.Action("tokens","Citizen")", function (data) {

            if (re.test(term) && term == data) {

                $("#sup2").hide();
                $("#sup3").show();
                return true;
```

}

Used this to access the variable. It worked.